# When applying for more positions at one institution, should I apply at once or consecutively?

Tags: application, job

There were two open positions at one research institution. I already applied for one because of the deadline. The second position has deadline in January. They are in different departments, the number of employees is above 100. I think I would prefer the second position because it is more senior and it is for three years while the first one is more like a postdoc and for one year. But both state they can be extended thereafter.

How should proceed now? Should I submit the second applications as soon as possible? Or should I wait if they contact me from the first one? I am not in touch with anybody from that institution, nor is my supervisor. I'v met some of them on a conference.

Comment: Same division within the institution or spread all over it?

Comment: What sort of position?

Comment: Are the positions in the same group? Do you know the PIs? Can you (or your advisor) contact the PIs even if you don't know them?

Comment: @Buffy I updated the question.

Comment: Just make the deadline for the January position unless something happens to change your mind. Nothing will happen to early applicants other than clerical sorting and such.

Comment: @Buffy OK, if they won't contact me from the first position I will submit the second application. But if they will contact me? Should I try to say that I am interested in the second position and I want to wait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not wait until you are contacted, because there is as substantial chance that will never happen.

So long as you apply before the deadline, the timing does not matter.  It is very likely that the two applications are evaluated completely separately, and even if they were not, timing is unlikely to be important.

Most universities have very little hiring activity in December.  Applications submitted in December or January are unlikely to result in job offers before February.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that you apply now for the first one and wait a bit. You will probably have some feedback by the deadline for the second one.

There is probably no real value in applying long before a deadline, provided that you can actually meet it with all requirements.

It is also unlikely that you would get a decision/offer before the second deadline, but more information can't hurt and might help..